# Django | How To Link Dynamic Data to Some Other Dynamic Data

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a IP inventory project and have the database model setup along with search working.  I setup another Model and imported my Nessus Vulnerability data.

I am trying to link the IP address from my inventory search result to the another view to show the info from the other model but I cant seem to get the filter right.  I get all the records or none when I click on the link.  Any direction would be appreciated!

Here is the function:

```
def nessusDATA(request):
items = NessusReports.objects.filter(Host=IPs.IP_Address)
context = {
    'items': items,
           }
return render(request, 'nessusdata.html', context)
```

Here is the link:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'nessusDATA' %}">{{item.IP_Address}}</td>
```

Here is the Model:

```
class NessusReports(models.Model):
Risk = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
Host = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Here is the URP.py

```
path('nessusDATA/str:Host', views.nessusDATA, name='Host'),
```

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```
path('nessusDATA/<str:Host>', views.nessusDATA, name='nessusDATA'),
```

views.py

```
def nessusDATA(request,Host):
    items = NessusReports.objects.filter(Host=Host)
    context = {
        'items': items,
               }
    return render(request, 'nessusdata.html', context)
```

link:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'nessusDATA' item.Host %}">{{item.Host}}</td>
```

give more details about your project if this doesn't work.

Comment: I tried what you recommended but no go.  Could it be because the IP address in one model is called Host and the other it is called IP_Address?

Comment: I have change URL name in url.py try it